# Jquery Tooltip does not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip

I'm trying to build a Table form a database (the table content is updated every x seconds)

Now I want a Tooltip for each table row for some more information (additional ajax query) for the users.

there are tablerows with a `123_tr` class.

```js
$("body").tooltip({ 
    selector: '.123_tr',
    items: "123_tr",
    track: true,
    content: function() {
        var element = $( this );
        return "123";
    }
});
```

I hover the mouse over a table row, the inspector shows me then changing attribute of the `tr`, but no Tooltip is visible.

Comment: I can't find the selector option in Jquery-UI documentation. Have you tried to do `$('.123_tr').tootip({ ... })` ? (link to the Doc : http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/ )